# Java Cipher Shifting Letters

Tags: java, encryption, unicode

I am currently trying to code a basic encryption program. I have it working, for the most part. It is just not quite working as I'd like. 
Basically, the user enters a phrase, a shift amount (e.g 5, being 5 letters forwards), and the program encrypts the phrase. 
For example, if the user entered "red" with a shift of 5, the program should print out: WJI
However, I got the program to work with the Unicode, so it is printing out the corresponding Unicode characters, so I am getting symbols, such as "{, :" in my encryption. It still works, mind you, but just not the way I am looking for.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class SimpleEncryption {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
static int shift;
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String cipher = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a sentence or word that you wish to encode or decode. This program uses"
           + " a basic cipher shift.");
  String upperCase = cipher.toUpperCase();
   char[] cipherArray = cipher.toCharArray(); 
   String rotationAmount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a shift amount.");
   int rotation = Integer.parseInt(rotationAmount);
   String encryptOrDecrypt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please choose whether to encrypt or decrypt this message. \n"
           + "Encrypt - press 1\nDecrypt - press 2");
   int choice = Integer.parseInt(encryptOrDecrypt);
   int cipherLength = cipherArray.length;

   if (choice == 1) { //if the user chooses to encrypt their cipher
       System.out.println("The original phrase is: "+upperCase);
       System.out.println("ENCRYPTED PHRASE:");
       for (int i = 0; i < cipherLength; i++) {
       shift = (upperCase.charAt(i) + rotation);
       System.out.print((char)(shift));
       }
       System.out.println(" ");
   }
       else if (choice == 2) {
          System.out.println("DECRYPTED PHRASE:");
               for (int i = 0; i < cipherLength; i++) {
                  shift = (cipher.charAt(i) - rotation);
                   System.out.print((char)(shift));
               }


               }


   }
```

}

Any and all suggestions are appreciated. Also, lets say the user enters a shift value of 25. How do I get the alphabet to "loop" around. E.g the letter is Z with a shift of 2 would make it "B"?

Comment: Hint: modulo operator: `%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
shift = cipher.charAt(i) - rotation
```

try

```
int tmp = cipher.charAt(i) - 'A';    // Offset from 'A'
int rotated = (tmp - rotation) % 26; // Compute rotation, wrap at 26 for chars
shift = rotated + 'A';               // Add back offset from 'A'
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this works. Would you mind explaining it to me? I understand that we are adding or subtracting letters, but what exactly is the modulus operator doing here? (sorry, beginner coder here)

Comment: You can't compute module 25 directly in ascii (since you want it to go between ascii values 'A' to 'Z' and not between ascii values of 0 to 25). So you start by computing the offset from 'A' (and store it in `tmp`). You can then use the modulo operator to make sure the computation wraps around 25. (second line). The result of the modulo computation is between 0 and 25, which means that you need to add back 'A' to make it an ascii value. (third line).